# SVG: using multiple system language options in a defined text

Tags: svg

I have a defined element an SVG image. Ideally, I'd like people you use the image to just have to substitute their local language in the defined element without having to rename the ID throughout the rest of the code.

```
<def>
<text id="label_1" systemlanguage="en" font-size="20px" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="bold" > C </text>
</def>
```

then I call "label_1" multiple times in the image but this doesn't help with recognizing the system language problem (a separate label would be required for each language).  Any idea how to make a universal label where each language just defines the same named id?  e.g.

```
<def>
<text id="label_1"font-size="20px" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="bold">
<systemlanguage="en"; C>
<systemlanguage="de"; D> </text>
</def>
```

or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this? Depending on your preferred UA language this will display different words.

```html
<svg>
  <switch>
    <text x="230" y="150" systemlanguage="en">English</text>
    <text x="230" y="150" systemLanguage="es">Spanish</text>
  </switch>
</svg>
```

That's as much as SVG does natively. Anything else would require javascript.

Comment: and if I want to use it as a defined element, do I put the ID in the switch element?<def>
  <switch id="label">
    <text  systemlanguage="en">English</text>
    <text  systemLanguage="es">Spanish</text>
  </switch> </def>
</svg>

Comment: You can't really use it as a defined element. What I've shown you is what you get.